# colorpick is not working on first onclick.It works on second click..needs answer

Tags: php, jquery, yii

```
<a href='#' onClick ='backcolor();' class='pagecolor' id='firstpage-right-pagecolor' >
<img src='". Yii::app()->baseURL.'/images/color.png'."'></a>
```

here i call backcolor function (important-Its in controller) and its definition is in view as follows..

```
   function backcolor() {
            $('.pagecolor').colpick({
                   onSubmit:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el){
                    var divid = $(el).closest('div').attr('id');
                    $('#'+divid).css('background-color', '#'+hex);
                    $(el).colpickHide();
                    $.ajax({
                          url:baseURL+'/index.php/MyPhotoBooks/addbackground',
                          type:'POST',
                          data:{color:hex,divid:divid},
                          success:function(){   
                                //$("#"+divid).css('height', '80%');
                        },
                    }); 
                }   
            });
        };
```

It works on second click only..for first click color pick not displaying..

Comment: In your HTML the function is called without argument when it seems to be expected one. Also I'm guessing the plugin needs to be initialized before it works which is what the function seem to do. So the first time you click it initialized the plugin and from there the plugin works. Try setting initializing the plugin on dom ready instead.

Comment: I had a misteke on my question Now Its edited..Thnks in advance..

Comment: Ah looking at the `colpick` doc this one doesn't need to be initialized first so that's not the issue. Any error in the console?

Comment: Actually there are no errors..but It works only on second click

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely expected behaviour.

You seem to be binding the colorpick to the element on click of the same element. You need to do that on page load instead.

**Recommended Solution:**

Change `onClick` to `onload`. This will make sure that when your element is loaded, the colorpicker is binded to it. Next when the colorpicker element is clicked, it should work.

```
<a href='#' onClick ='backcolor();' class='pagecolor' id='firstpage-right-pagecolor' >
```

to

```
<a href='#' onload ='backcolor();' class='pagecolor' id='firstpage-right-pagecolor' >
```

**-----Alternative Approach---------**

Showing the colorpick on click of the element is automatically handled by the plugin. So simply change your function code to

```
$(function(){
        $('.pagecolor').colpick({
               onSubmit:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el){
                var divid = $(el).closest('div').attr('id');
                $('#'+divid).css('background-color', '#'+hex);
                $(el).colpickHide();
                $.ajax({
                      url:baseURL+'/index.php/MyPhotoBooks/addbackground',
                      type:'POST',
                      data:{color:hex,divid:divid},
                      success:function(){   
                            //$("#"+divid).css('height', '80%');
                    },
                }); 
            }   
        });
});
```

This will ensure binding on page load. Also make sure to remove `onclick` handler from your `.pagecolor` element.

Comment: No its not working..call comes from controller..unless there is no onclick function its not working

Comment: Exactly, you need to bind the colorpicker **before** the first click.

Comment: Let me put it this way, whenever the first click happens, you call the function `backcolor`.
This function then attaches the plugin to the element.

So the next time you click on the element, the colorpicker plugin handles the click.